# Nats Messaging System - Nodejs Nats client request & requestOne method

Tags: node.js

I'm familiar with Nats concept and have tried its command pub, sub and connect. Also, I've gone through the concept group-queue & pub-sub-reply. But while I was reading the nodeJS **[Nats client](https://github.com/nats-io/node-nats)**, I found that two methods request and requestOne. I don't know what is the use of this methods ?

```
 var sid = nats.request('request', function(response) {
  console.log('Got a response in msg stream: ' + response);
});

// Request with Auto-Unsubscribe. Will unsubscribe after
// the first response is received via {'max':1}
nats.request('help', null, {'max':1}, function(response) {
  console.log('Got a response for help: ' + response);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, it appears that *requestOne* is just a helper function to automatically cancel the subscription after it receives a message back.  It's basically the same call but with an explicit { max : 1 } option .. In fact, it sets up the options and then just calls the regular *request* method.